buckets in GCP MQL
I want to group the age with the span of 5 and count number of rows in each bucket. I'm using log-based counter metrics with age as label.
Does anyone have experience of using MQL in GCP monitoring and grouping output table into buckets?
MQL Query:
fetch cloud_run_revision
metric 'logging.googleapis.com/user/Age_Metric'
| align delta()
| map update[age: abs(age)]
| map [age]

Output:
|------|
| age  |
|------|
| 24   |    
| 7    |
|------|

Expected:
|--------|------|
| bucket   count|
|--------|------|
| 20-25  |   1  |
| 6-10   |   1  |
|--------|------|

I've checked the documentation but not able to find anything useful in that.
